# Filtering Tableau Measure names in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard where I need to show only particular measure names .

I took required measure values and In the measure names filter it still showing the names I filtered as unchecked.
I need remove them and show only the measure names I selected.

Could anyone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can do this by [hiding all of the measures](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-measure-names-filter/) you don't want to appear in the filter. A downside is you aren't able to use the hidden measures in the workbook.

Comment: For this reason, I would've preferred the 'parameter' way of solution.